# c question for beginners

Tags: c

```
main()
{
  int x=5,y=3;
  x=x+~y+1;
  printf("%d",x);
}
```

What would the output be?

Comment: whatwould be the output?

Comment: @bandana try putting your code in a .c file and compiling it with your favorite compiler (gcc for example).

Comment: It would have been better if the question was what does the tilde (~) operator do in C.

Comment: ~ operator is the bitwise complement operator if I m not wrong.

Comment: I've nominated the question for reopening because it is now asking a real question.  However, surely bandana could just compile and run it to get the answer.

Comment: The proper close reason is "too localized". @bandana: If you have a particular problem understanding this code, please *ask about the thing you don't 'get'*. Questions of this form are of no use to anybody coming in the future on top of which, they give prospective answer writers no guidance in terms of what to explain.

Answer (score 4):

If your question was "What does this output?", why didn't you just type it in and test it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int x=5,y=3;
    x = x + ~y + 1;
    printf ("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs `2` *on my system.* How about yours?

---

If you print out `y` and `~y`, you'll get `3` and `-4` respectively (on a two's complement architecture).

That's because, with two's complement, you can get the negative of a number by inverting all the bits then adding 1. So `~y + 1` (the tilde means "invert all bits") is effectively `-y`.

```
   x + ~y + 1
=  x + (~y + 1)
=  x + (-y)
=  x - y
=  5 - 3
=  2
```

*Aside:* I don't think that ISO actually mandates an underlying two's complement architecture for storing numbers so that may not work on *all* implementations. However, it's been a long time since I saw such a beast. And, to be honest, if you want to get the negative of a number, why wouldn't you just use `-y`?

Comment: @Aaron, what machine are you using (or was that some humour that just went whooshing past me)? :-)

Comment: @paxdiable whoosh.... ;)